# New Share intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

I noticed that some apps like `DropBox` and `Google +` have a new look for sharing which looks pretty nice :
[image]

which might be scrolled to the top.

Is this sharing with intents ? or is this a custom way to share ? (note : both Drpbox and Google+ have same sharing view design)

Thank you.

Comment: You can create a customAdapter for this dialog http://clickclickclack.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/intercepting-androids-action_send-intents/

Comment: Why not try building a simple demo with a sharing intent and run it on a device/emulator running the latest version of Android and see what happens?

Comment: @Pavlos : oh, thank you ! so it's not something native, right ?

Comment: @Calvedos : I actually have android 4.4.4 and the sharing intent is the same as the old one :)

Comment: I suppose not but you never know!